# Toggle all bits except after highest set bit

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, binary-operators

How can I toggle all bits of a number except after the highest set bit?

**For Example:**
Let's suppose a 32-bit number that needs to be toggled.

```
00000000000000000010011110000100  // Input

00000000000000000001100001111011  // Expected
```

How could I achieve this in a java/C++??

Comment: The value shown as `// Expected` is not what I expected interpreting `toggle all bits of a number except after the highest set bit` and seeing the `// Input`: the highest bit set is toggled, too. If&when trying to improve the wording, please use more than one bit in the title, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do the follow. For given `n = 10011110000100`

1. We'll find the *smallest* **power of 2** `v = 100...00` such that `v > n`.
2. Then `result = n ^ (v - 1)` (note that `b XOR 1` *toggles* bit `b`)

What's going on:

```
n           =  10011110000100
v           = 100000000000000
v - 1       =  11111111111111
n ^ (v - 1) =  01100001111011
```

**Code:**

```
int n = 0b10011110000100;

int v = 1;

while (v <= n)
  v <<= 1;

int result = n ^ (v - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
public static int toggle(int n) {
  int m = n;
  m |= m >>> 1;
  m |= m >>> 2;
  m |= m >>> 4;
  m |= m >>> 8;
  m |= m >>> 16;
  return n ^ m;
}
```

The repeated lines with powers of two, whose purpose is to set in `m` the most significant set bit of `n` and all bits less significant than it, can be replaced by a special instruction to find the number of leading zeros if you have access to such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The following implementations illustrate the efficient use of powers of 2 that David Eisenstat used but in languages which provide arbitrarily large integers, such as Python or Ruby.  In other words, these solutions are not hardwired for 32 bit integers.  I tested the Ruby version with inputs as large as 2<sup>1000</sup>.

### Ruby

```ruby
def toggle(n)
  shift = 1
  m = n
  while (1 << shift) <= n
    m |= m >> shift
    shift <<= 1
  end
  m ^ n
end
```

### Python

```python
def toggle(n):
  shift = 1
  m = n
  while (1 << shift) <= n:
    m |= m >> shift
    shift <<= 1
  return m ^ n
```

You used the tag `language-agnostic`, so I'm taking you at your word even though you mention C++ and Java in your question.